# the fundamental group of double torus( $T\#T$) is not abelian

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I find this proof from Munkres Topology lacking rigour and a lot of precision.

**can someone write down the equations that have been mentioned in the proof and probably provide some feeling or intuition for them?**

**does the intersection point of the figure eight of $T\#T$ lie on the dotted circle, because if it does then the inverse of $h$ would map back the intersection point of the figure eight in $Y$ to the whole dotted circle and wouldn't be a homeomorphism, right?**

[image]

Comment: You should read carefuly the book. You actually pasted only piece of the full sentence. The full sentence is: "it defines a homeomorphism $h$ of the figure eight in $T\#T$ with the figure eight in $Y$". And so $h$ is not defined on full $T\# T$, only on the figure eight.